# How do I determine whether components of an array where numbers and letters are combined succeed each other on the basis of the numbers?

Tags: bash, shell-script, linux-mint

I have an array with contents: `${array[0]}="h4"`, `${array[1]}="q2"`, `${array[2]}="s7"`, `${array[3]}="r1"`, `${array[4]}="h3"` and i want to determine if the numbers in those arrays (4, 2, 7, 1, 3) succeed each other or not.
What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Are the numbers always the 2nd character of the value?

Comment: yes they always start as the second character, but then can also be longer that 1 character for example: ${array[]}="a14"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might deploy you recent question's answers like

```
$ ARR=(h4 q2 s7 r1 h3)
$ SA=( $(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${ARR[*]}" | sort -k1.2n) )
$ [ "${ARR[*]}" == "${SA[*]}" ] && echo in seq || echo out of seq
out of seq
```

The `n`umeric `sort` allows for multi digit numbers from the second char on.

**EDIT:** or, even shorter,

```
( IFS=$'\n'; [ "${ARR[*]}" == "$(sort -k1.2n <<< "${ARR[*]}" )"  ] )  && echo in seq || echo out of seq
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below initializes a "last one" variable then loops through the array (starting at the second element) and checks to see if that element is smaller than the previous one; if it is, the code echos a failure message and stops the loop.

```
lastone=${array[0]:1}
for((i=1; i < ${#array[@]}; i++))
do
  if (( "${array[i]:1}" < "$lastone" ))
  then
    echo failure
    break
  fi
  lastone=${array[i]:1}
done
```

Alternatively, ask bash to print each element on its own line while stripping out the first/leading character, then pipe that to `sort` and ask if the input is sorted:

```
if printf '%d\n' "${array[@]/#?/}" | sort -cn 2>/dev/null
then
  echo is sorted
else
  echo is not sorted
fi
```